# How to run sanitizers on whole project

Tags: cmake, clang, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to get familiar with sanitizers as ASAN, LSAN etc and got a lot of useful information already from here: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/05/05/memory-error-checking-in-c-and-c-comparing-sanitizers-and-valgrind

I am able to run all sort of sanitizers on specific files, as shown on the site, like this:

```
clang -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g ../TestFiles/ASAN_TestFile.c
ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/local/bin/llvm-symbolizer ./a.out >../Logs/ASAN_C.log 2>&1
```

which generates a log with found issue. Now I would like to extend this to run upon building the project with cmake. This is the command to build it at the moment:

```
cmake -S . -B build
cd build
make
```

Is there any way I can use this script with adding the sanitizers, without having to alter the cmakelist.txt file??

For instance something like this:

```
cmake -S . -B build
cd build
make -fsanitize=address
./a.out >../Logs/ASAN_C.log 2>&1
```

The reason is that I want to be able to build the project multiple times with different sanitizers (since they cannot be used together) and have a log created without altering the cmakelist.txt file (just want to be able to quickly test the whole project for memory issues instead of doing it for each file created).

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional compiler flags from command line during the build configuration:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fsanitize=address" -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fsanitize=address"  /path/to/CMakeLists.txt
```

If your CMakeLists.txt is configured properly above should work. If that does not work then try adding flags as environment variable:

```
cmake -E env CXXFLAGS="-fsanitize=address" CFLAGS="-fsanitize=address"  /path/to/CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. Will have to add some intentional errors to see if they are correctly caught and written to log.

Comment: So, the second command is cmake running CMake?

Comment: Good catch. it was a typo.